# how apt-get knows where to look for packages

Tags: debian

If I just run `apt-get update` (without any package name)  on a new installation, the OS download/updates the packages. How does it know which packages to download and from where? Is the list of `sources` pre-configured in the `OS` eg. in Debian?

Comment: After almost a year on this site, you should know that Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. Your question seems more suitable for [ubuntu.se] but read their help (too) before posting there (in particular, search before asking).

Comment: This doesn't really belong on StackOverflow (there are many sister sites) but yes ubuntu, debian, RHEL, centos all come with their own default repositories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have nearly answered the question yourself. Let me add a little light to help you have a better understanding.

The package manager(apt or apt-get) gets the list of installed packages from the sources. The sources are simply locations where packages( software ) can be downloaded. We can add or remove sources from a Debian system.

When you run `sudo apt-get update` no software package has been specified to be updated hence, the system looks for updates for all the installed software packages from the sources. You can think of it like a wild card.

But, when you run `sudo apt-get update vlc` for instance, the system will only look for updates pertaining to the **vlc** package.

For more understanding read about how `getopts is used in shell scripts.`